# how can i set left undefined in jquery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've a array like

```
[undefined,"3px","3px",undefined,"3px",undefined,"3px",undefined]
```

it is marked direction like css;

so I want use

```
$(dom).animate{
        top:arr[0],
        right:arr[1],
        bottom:arr[2],
        left:arr[3],
}
```

but it always set top:0 right0 ,although it has seted undefined;
thanks

---

```
thank you ;
i am sorry to expression not correct;
i've solve  it in other ways.
Simply say it's when i've set the dom left ;
than use animate to set the right property ;
it's not work because css property can't set left and right in time;
i'hava a lot of dom.Some set left and some set right ;
Some animate right and some animate left;
i make an array 4 direction one dom;
so i want to ask there is any way to remove css property in animate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map `undefined` to `"+=0px"`, so the animation becomes a no-op for undefined components:

```
var components = [
    undefined, "3px", "3px", undefined, "3px", undefined, "3px", undefined
];
var animComponents = $.map(components, function(value) {
    return value === undefined ? "+=0px" : value;
});

$(dom).animate({
    top: animComponents[0],
    right: animComponents[1],
    bottom: animComponents[2],
    left: animComponents[3]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set `css` value as `undefined`. You can convert the value to `0` when your array value is `undefined` instead:

```
$(dom).animate{
    top: arr[0] == "undefined" ? 0 : arr[0],
    right: arr[1] == "undefined" ? 0 : arr[1],
    bottom: arr[2] == "undefined" ? 0 : arr[2],
    left: arr[3] == "undefined" ? 0 : arr[3],
}
```

Comment: Shorter will be ```arr[0] || 0```, ```arr[1] || 0```, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the `css` understands an `undefined` value. Try switching out `undefined` with `0` or `0px` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check datatype of variable using    typeof()

```
 $(dom).animate{
   top: typeof(arr[0]) == "undefined" ? 0 : arr[0],
   right: typeof(arr[1])  == "undefined" ? 0 : arr[1],
   bottom: typeof(arr[2])  == "undefined" ? 0 : arr[2],
  left: typeof(arr[3])  == "undefined" ? 0 : arr[3],
 }
```